# Caching database table on a high-performance application

Tags: database, caching, distributed-computing, distributed-caching

I have a high-performance application I'm considering making distributed (using rabbitMQ as the MQ). The application uses a database (currently SQLServer, but I can still switch to something else) and caches most of it in the RAM to increase performance.
This causes a problem because when one of the applications writes to the database, the others' cached database becomes out-of-date.

I figured it is something that happens a lot in the High-Availability community, however I couldn't find anything useful. I guess I'm not searching for the right thing.
Is there an out-of-the-box solution?

PS: I'm sorry if this belongs to serverfault - Since this a development issue I figured it belongs here

EDIT:
The application reads and writes to the database. Since I'm changing the application to be distributed - Now more than one application reads and writes to the database. The caching is done in each of the distributed applications, which are not aware to DB changes from another application.
I mean - How can one know if the DB was updated, if he wasn't the one to update it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when one of the applications writes to the database, the others' cached database becomes out-of-date."  Do you have multiple applications sharing the database?  What kind of cache?  Is it a cache local to the application, or ... ?

Comment: Edited the original question to try and clarify things

Comment: Paul I'd do that but I do need the performance boost :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have one database and many applications on various servers.  Each application has its own cache and all the applications are reading and writing to the database.

Look at a distributed cache instead of caching locally.  Check out memcached or AppFabric.  I've had success using AppFabric to cache things in a Microsoft stack.  You can simply add new nodes to AppFabric and it will automatically distribute the objects for high availability.

If you move to a shared cache, then you can put expiration times on objects in the cache.  Try to resist the temptation to proactively evict items when things change.  It becomes a very difficult problem.

I would recommend isolating your critical items and only cache them once.  As an example, when working on an auction site, we cached very aggressively.  We only cached an auction  listing's price once.  That way when someone else bid on it, we only had to do one eviction.  We didn't have to go through the entire cache and ask "Where does the price appear?  Change it!"

For 95% of your data, the reads will expire on their own and writes won't affect them immediately.  5% of your data needs to be evicted when a new write comes in.  This is what I called your "critical items".  Things that always need to be up to date.

Hope that gives you ideas!

Comment: Distributed caching... Sounds like the what I need. Do you have any experience with that under C++ environment?

Comment: I don't, but check out the C++ memcached clients.  http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients